# Saving Word Document in Powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I want to replace a few pieces of text in a Word document.

Here is the entire script:

```
param (
    [string]$TemplateFile = $PSScriptRoot + '/test.docx',
    [string]$NewFile = $PSScriptRoot + '/test2.docx',
    [string]$FindTextDate = '_date',
    [string]$FindTextPos = '_pos',
    [string]$FindTextCom = '_com',
    [string]$ReplaceTextDate = $(Get-Date -UFormat '%B %e, %Y'),
    [string]$ReplaceTextPos = $(Read-Host -Prompt 'Position Name'),
    [string]$ReplaceTextCom = $(Read-Host -Prompt 'Company Name')
)

# check that template file exists
if (!(Test-Path $TemplateFile)) {
    throw '-TemplateFile does not exist.'
}

# create new file from template file
Copy-Item $TemplateFile $NewFile

# options for replacement
$MatchCase = $false
$MatchWholeWord = $false
$MatchWildcards = $false
$MatchSoundsLike = $false
$MatchAllWordForms = $false
$Forward = $false
$Wrap = 1
$Format = $false
$Replace = 2

# open document and replace
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $false
$Document = $Word.Documents.Open($NewFile)
$Document.Content.Find.Execute($FindTextDate, $MatchCase, $MatchWholeWord, $MatchWildcards, $MatchSoundsLike, $MatchAllWordForms, $Forward, $Wrap, $Format, $ReplaceTextDate, $Replace)
$Document.Content.Find.Execute($FindTextPos, $MatchCase, $MatchWholeWord, $MatchWildcards, $MatchSoundsLike, $MatchAllWordForms, $Forward, $Wrap, $Format, $ReplaceTextPos, $Replace)
$Document.Content.Find.Execute($FindTextCom, $MatchCase, $MatchWholeWord, $MatchWildcards, $MatchSoundsLike, $MatchAllWordForms, $Forward, $Wrap, $Format, $ReplaceTextCom, $Replace)
$Document.Save()
$Document.Close()
$Word.Quit()
```

It is failing at `Document.Save()` with the following error:

```
+ $Document.Save()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

I tried taking out `Document.Save()` and just using `Document.Close(-1)`, and I got the following error:

```
+ $Document.Close()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

Furthermore, when I manually save it in the save prompt, I am not seeing any of the changes being reflected in the document even though all three `$Document.Content.Find.Execute` statements are returning true.

---

As pointed out by mjsqu, changing it to `$Word.Visible = $true` and
`$Word.ScreenUpdating = $true` made it work, but I was hoping to do this without any visual effects.

Comment: Try making the document visible and turn ScreenUpdating on while testing? `$Word.visible = $true`, `$Word.ScreenUpdating = $true` - that way any dialog boxes shown during the save operation should show up and you may learn more from what they say

Comment: The Word ComObject really likes references. I'm betting `$Document.Close([ref] -1)` would work fine for you.

Comment: $Word.visible = $true, $Word.ScreenUpdating = $true worked for me, however I am still curious if there is a way to do this without any visual updates.

Comment: adding the ref did not change anything

Comment: I have tested your script, but **there are no errors**, and the text that should be replaced is **correctly replaced**. test2.docx is also **saved and read properly**.  All in the background running. (ie. *$Word.Visible = $false*) From the error message you provided guessed that **it may not be a script problem**, but **Word or Office installation problems or Office version does not support** , you can think again from this direction. In short, I can help you to endorse the script is no problem.